# How to import a dialog (and code) to libreoffice calc

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I had written some code and a small dialog for simplifying some processes for an older version of calc.

In order to load a dialog in the old versions of calc, i could go to the menu "Tools | Macros | Organize Dialogs", choose "import dialog" (an icon showing a document with a plus symbol) and then load my dialog resource ("dlgCSVLoad.xdl")

In the current version (7.2.5.2) there seems to be no (obvious) possibility to load a dialog resource anymore.

What steps do i have to take to import a dialog resource (in xdl format) into libreoffice calc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit an existing dialog. You can create a new one for this purpose if you want. Then go to *File > Import Dialog*.

It's also possible to copy the file directly into a library under the `basic` directory in your LibreOffice user profile. Then edit `dialog.xlb` to tell it which file you added.

Comment: I used yxour first suggestion and it worked well. Thanks